# 100% width table with three colums in div

Tags: html, html-table, width

I'm trying to make a webpage with a table in a div.
The table has a 100% width with three columns.
But when I resize the window the table doesn't adjust its width.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width: 1400px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: aqua; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px">Text.</td>
        <td style="background-color: #DD185B; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px">Text.</td>
        <td style="background-color: aqua; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px">Text.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Table is 100% width of Parent element. In your case the parent element is a DIV with fixed width of 1400px. Remove the width property of parent DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `width: 1400px` to `max-width: 1400px;`

width is fixed, max width is the max you can go up to.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="max-width: 1400px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color: aqua; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px">Text.</td>
          <td style="background-color: #DD185B; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px">Text.</td>
          <td style="background-color: aqua; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px">Text.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thnx m8! Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The table's width is 100% of the parent element, in this case your div. Your div is set to 1400px, therefore the table is 1400px as well.

Answer (score 0):

div width is fixing the css property.

https://jsfiddle.net/jst9u4zv/

```
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: aqua; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px">Text.</td>
        <td style="background-color: #DD185B; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px">Text.</td>
        <td style="background-color: aqua; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px">Text.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```